# Testing library functions with Javascript & Truffle

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

I'm trying to test functions of a library with Truffle. But they don't seem to be available.

The library is named `Commons` and I include it as I would include a contract:

```
var Commons = artifacts.require("./Commons.sol");
```

But if I do

```
let foo = Commons.new();
let returnValue = foo.getBalancePeriod(5);
```

I get:

```
TypeError: foo.getBalancePeriod is not a function
```

If I instead do

```
let returnValue = Commons.getBalancePeriod(5);
```

I just get:

```
TypeError: Commons.getBalancePeriod is not a function
```

I made sure that the function name is exactly as it was defined in the library but the function just doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let us know the result:

```
var Commons = artifacts.require("./Commons.sol");

contract("Commons", function(accounts) {
    it('should revert the transaction of getBalancePeriod if conditions are not met', function() {
        return Commons.deployed()
        .then(function (instance) {
            return instance.getBalancePeriod(5);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm.

Comment: Well, the functions need to be async because I need to await the result. But then it works like a charm. (Without it, it at least doesn't crash anymore but only returns a promise.)